# Setting MySQLDump to keep running in the background after session times out

Tags: mysql, linux, mysqldump

I'm tryng to set up a new Slave DB by copying another Slave DB. Normally I would simply use `MySQLDump` to dump the Slave and create a `.sql` file, then import that into the new database.

However, as our new server is a Linux (Debian 7) server (the slave I'm copying is on a Windows server), I figured I would try to pipe the dump straight into the new database. This seemed to go well, until my putty session expired and it all stopped.

I tried it again, this time using `nohup .... &`. But still the dump stopped as soon as my session expired.

Is there a way to make this work? My full dump command is:

`nohup mysqldump -hxxx -P3306 -uxxx -pxxx --dump-slave --databases a b c d --ignore-table=a.xxx -F | mysql -h127.0.0.1 -P3306 -uxxx -pxxx &`

All DB's are MySQL 5.5.

Answer (score 4):

I think I found the problem. Apparently the `nohup` command ended at the `|` symbol, so when the session expired the second part of the command stopped with the session.

To get round this I ran:

`nohup sh -c 'mysqldump -hxxx -P3306 -uxxx -pxxx --dump-slave --databases a b c d --ignore-table=a.xxx -F | mysql -h127.0.0.1 -P3306 -uxxx -pxxx' &`

I checked it was running, and then `EXIT`ed the shell, and so far, it is still running.

Comment: alternatively use `screen` :)

Answer (score 3):

Another jazzy approach to this would be to place that command without the ampersand into a shell script. Then, execute the script, by name, in the background. For example, call the shell script `transfer_mysql_data.sh` in the `/path/to/script` folder.

Here is the content of this proposed script

```
SCRIPT_TO_RUN=/path/to/script/transfer_mysql_data.sh
RUNLOG=/path/to/script/transfer_mysql_data.log
date > ${RUNLOG}
mysqldump -hxxx -P3306 -uxxx -pxxx --dump-slave --databases a b c d --ignore-table=a.xxx -F | mysql -h127.0.0.1 -P3306 -uxxx -pxxx
date >> ${RUNLOG}
chmod -x ${SCRIPT_TO_RUN}
```

You perform the following

```
cd /path/to/script
chmod +x transfer_mysql_data.sh
nohup ./transfer_mysql_data.sh &
```

You can immediately logout and come back later.

You could then poll the run log file `/path/to/script/transfer_mysql_data.log` to see when the mysqldump transfer finished. It will be finished when there are two lines: start datetime and end datetime.